# Android mediaplayer setdatasource

Tags: android, url, media-player, playlist

I have a tricky question regarding the MediaPlayer class.

I would like to find a way to play MORE than ONE online song. I though of doing it with soundcloud, but clearly the website of a playlist will not work out.

Therefore I thought of adding several string referring to single songs on soundcloud by deploying the ".setDataSource" but the app crashes, aka I cant have more than one string.

Hence, I tried with only one, but the single song's page from SoundCloud does not work either. Apparently it only works with online mp3.

Now, getting online .mp3 lawfully is rather hard nowadays and I was looking for a way to play mp3 (or m3u) from an authorised website or possibly even a playlist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google's `ExoPlayer` , its powerful, flexible and supports adaptive streaming. You can get to know more about it in [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), also the [github page.](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)